# saving new property overwrites firebase object

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am working on a quiz using firebase and angular. At the end of the quiz i want to save a new property to the users object using this code:

```
function saveTopscore() {
    var ref = new Firebase(CONSTANTS.FIREBASE_URL + 'users/' + User.user.$id + '/');
    var userObject = $firebaseObject(ref);
    userObject.topscore = User.totalCorrect;
    userObject.$save().then(function(ref) {
        console.log("worked");
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

And it works, but it also overwrite all the properties of the user object. So the object used to hold like a name, username, email, password etc, but when i push the topscore it becomes the only property of the object. Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why are you using `$firebaseObject` here? That is only useful if you three-way bind it to an Angular view. If you're in regular JavaScript code, just stick to Firebase's regular JavaScript SDK.

In this case, just do:

```
ref.update({ topscore: User.totalCorrect });
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! I did it because it said so in the api docs. But this is much easier.

Comment: I'm fairly positive the API docs don't say to use $bindTo or any AngularFire bindings if you aren't going to synchronize the data for use in a view or service. (hint: I wrote them)

Answer (score 1):

As @Frank said, use the JavaScript SDK.

I wanted to clarify the original context (using `$firebaseObject`) in case anyone else refers to this question in the future.

- The original symptom is happening because you're setting a single parameter of the object and saving it before the object (and its already-existing children) have been fully downloaded.
- So, at the time when you call `.$save()`, `userObject` will (most likely) only have its `topscore` parameter set, and calling `.$save()` will effectively remove all of the other pre-existing children at the Firebase ref.

You could avoid this using [`.$loaded()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject-loaded) to wait until the object has fully downloaded before modifying and/or updating it...

**EDIT:** However, as the [Intro to AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/intro-to-angularfire.html#section-async-intro) guide states,

> The [`$loaded()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject-loaded) method should be used with care as it's only called once after initial load. Using it for anything but debugging is usually a poor practice.

If you were to ignore this warning and use `$loaded()` anyway, that implementation could look like this:

**Note - ANTIPATTERN: This is not a recommended practice.**

```js
var ref = new Firebase(fbUrl + '/users/' + User.user.$id + '/');
var userObject = $firebaseObject(ref);
// wait until userObject has been downloaded, then modify & save it.
userObject.$loaded().then(function(){
  userObject.topscore = User.totalCorrect;
  userObject.$save().then(function(ref) {
      console.log("Saved");
  }, function(error) {
      console.log(error);
  });
});
```

As Frank said in the comments to this answer,

> "If you're using `$loaded()` straight after `$firebaseObject` (or `$firebaseArray`), you're probably doing something wrong."

Comment: Hey Sinan. Your approach works too. But I have started using a rule: "if you're using `$loaded()` straight after `$firebaseObject` (or `$firebaseArray`), you're probably doing something wrong". We see way too much use of `$loaded()` and I'm going to show why people don't need it where I can. ;-)   Still... you solution definitely works too.

Comment: Hi Frank. That's a great point, and that's a great rule! Thanks for clarifying. I was hoping to explain the process of how data is downloaded. I now see in [Intro to AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/intro-to-angularfire.html#section-async-intro) that using `$loaded()` for something other than debugging is considered poor practice. If `$loaded()` is being overused, any plans for addressing that? I think it would be awesome to have a list of functional anti-patterns as a reference.

Comment: That new documentation you found is one way we try to be more explicit. But it remains tricky. We often tell people to simply bind the `$firebaseObject` to an element in their view. It will accomplish what they try to do (debug that/what data gets retrieved) with a lot less code, which is what AngularFire is all about.

Comment: Great discussion and great ideas. Sinan, if you run across anything you think might be a good usage or antipattern, email it in and we'll add to docs.

Comment: Hello Kato. Awesome, I definitely will. Thanks!

Comment: @SinanBolel I think why people keep making the above mistake and will probably choose $loaded instead of simply using the SDK update is the SDK update does not return a promise... But firebaseObject will. So use it in service we do not need go tho the trouble to create a $q and return promise back to controller. So I think the $loaded method is a lot more straight forward in Angular environment (correct me is I am wrong). But Frank's statement of "you're probably doing something wrong" does scary me to do it this way now...