# Using .numChildren() in AngularFire

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to use `.numChildren()` in AngularFire, but not sure I'm doing it correctly.

```
function getServiceProviders(serviceId) {
  var serviceProviders = ref.child('services').child(serviceId).child('providers');
  return serviceProviders.numChildren();
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: e.numChildren is not a function
```

Not sure if this is due to me using Browserify, or I'm just trying to access `numChildren` incorrectly.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Your code snippet doesn't use AngularFire, it only uses the Firebase JavaScript SDK. Although your project undoubtedly uses AngularFire, it doesn't relate to this question.*

When you look at the [documentation for the `.child()` method in the Firebase JavaScript SDK](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/child.html), you'll see that it returns a [Firebase reference](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/). And if you look further into that class, you should notice that it doesn't have a `numChildren` method.

[`numChildren`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/numchildren.html) is only available on a [`DataSnapshot`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/) object, which you get in any of the `on(...` event handlers.

So:

```
serviceProviders.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.numChildren());
}
```

Since the snapshot will be loaded asynchronously, you cannot return the number of children from `getServiceProviders`. See my answer to this question for a broader explanation of that: [Asynchronous access to an array in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049342/asynchronous-access-to-an-array-in-firebase/27050749#27050749)

Comment: I did initially have my `getServicesProvider` wrapped in a `$firebaseObject`, that's probably why I filed it under Angular Fire. Whats the difference between your approach, and `var getServicesProvider = $firebaseObject(ref.child('services').child(serviceId).child('providers')); getServicesProvider.$loaded().then(function(){ });` ?

Comment: In general: "when you use `$loaded()` in AngularFire, you are likely doing something wrong". I had a decent discussion with Sinan about that yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29835485/209103. Also please read this section of the documentation again, as it has recently been expanded to make the asynchronous nature more clear: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/intro-to-angularfire.html#section-async-intro

Comment: I always saw the Angular Fire API referencing `$loaded`, hence the reason I used it but thanks for this. I'll keep that in mind.