# firebaseObject $save() replaces the content of reference

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I can't make $save() work (i'm using firebaseObject)

```
 var user = new Firebase("URL");
 user.name = 'mark';
 user.$save();
```

After this my user's all records are simply replaced by a single

```
name: mark
```

Comment: This code won't run, since `Firebase` is an object from the Firebase JavaScript SDK, while `$save` is only defined in AngularFire. If you want to update *some* properties of an object, just do `new Firebase("url").update({ name: 'mark' });` See the documentation for `update` here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/update.html

Comment: This example could use some work. See [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You've used a Firebase reference as an angular $firebaseObject service here, given no context and no real understanding. Also, $save() does replace the contents, yes. That's expected behavior.

Comment: In addition to the comments above, see the [this answer for "_saving new property overwrites firebase object_"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29835485/1526037) if you wish to continue working with AngularFire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data isn't loaded yet in your example. You'll have to wait by hooking into the firebase .on or (as it seems you're using angularfire) you can look into working with $loaded based on the reference.

```
var user = $firebaseObject(new Firebase("URL"));
user.$loaded().then(function(){
    user.name = 'mark';
    user.$save();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, i missed the $firebaseObject in code sample above.
The problem was that my firebaseObject was not loaded yet. $loaded() fixed it. Here is the final working code:

```
var user = $firebaseObject(new Firebase("URL"));
user.$loaded().then(function(){
   user.name = 'mark';
   user.$save();
});
```