# Update Value of Firebase Children

Tags: regex, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to update the "name" on all children of my `services` item in Firebase, to remove all leading and trailing spaces. I'm using a regex to carry this out, but I can't seem to work out why it isn't working.

I'm looping through my `services` item using `.forEach` on its snapshot, but it doesn't seem to be saving the new value to Firebase.

Is this because I should be using `$save` on a `$firebaseObject`?

This is what my code looks like:

```
var servicesRef = ref.child('services');

servicesRef.on('value', function(snap) {
  snap.forEach(function(serviceSnap) {
    var item = serviceSnap;
    item.name = name.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
    item.$save();
  });
});
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I can only use AngularFire's `$save()` method on a `$firebaseObject`, so I used a different technique:

```
var obj = $firebaseObject(servicesRef);

obj.$loaded().then(function() {
   angular.forEach(obj, function(value, key) {
      var singleServiceRef = servicesRef.child(key);
      var serviceObj = $firebaseObject(singleServiceRef);
      var name = value.name;
      name = name.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
      serviceObj.name = name;
      serviceObj.$save();
   });
 });
```

Hope this helps others.

Comment: Hi realph. This is considered to be an anti-pattern with AngularFire - check out the comments on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29835485/1526037).  As @FrankvanPuffelen says, "_If you're using `$loaded()` straight after `$firebaseObject` (or `$firebaseArray`), you're probably doing something wrong._"

Comment: Good to know. I was only using it for bit of debugging to remove some white space from some strings. That said if I wanted to do something similar in production what would be the best way to do it?

Comment: You would fix it on initial insert/update, not everytime you get the list.

Comment: Ahh, so let's say we had a `create()` function, I would run that regex on that string inside the function before saving it to Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing item.name.replace instead of name.replace:

```
var item = serviceSnap;
item.name = item.name.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
item.$save();
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: `e.name.replace is not a function`. It's worth mentioning that I'm using browserify to bundle my JS.